# If I imigration from pickle to csv how should i do?

Tags: python, csv, pickle, loaddata

If I imigration from pickle to csv to open dataset (vector in csv) how should i do?

```
def load_data(dataset='mnist.pkl.gz'):
      dataset = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], '../data', dataset)
      f = gzip.open(dataset, 'rb')
      train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
      f.close()

      def make_numpy_array(data_xy):
      data_x, data_y = data_xy
      return numpy.array(data_x), numpy.array(data_y)


     train_set_x, train_set_y = make_numpy_array(train_set)
     valid_set_x, valid_set_y = make_numpy_array(valid_set)
     test_set_x, test_set_y = make_numpy_array(test_set)

     rval = [(train_set_x, train_set_y), (valid_set_x, valid_set_y),
      (test_set_x, test_set_y)]

      return rval
```

Comment: Are you sure you need (or want) to? They don't serve the same purpose. What do `train_set`, `valid_set`, and `test_set` look like?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I have a dataset of csv, because I do not understand to make my datset in pickle I want to open it from csv.

Comment: If you already have a dataset in CSV format, what does pickling have to do with this? Just use the `csv` module to read your CSV file.

Comment: I am confused, do I need to use os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0]? I don't understand that...

Comment: That has nothing to do with CSV or picking; that is just building an absolute file path relative to the location of the script itself.

Comment: for pickle.load what should I do? do i change numpy.load or etc? but when i change i get message ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking. If you have a CSV file, you don't use `pickle` at all; you use the `csv` module. If you want to create a CSV file that contains the same data that you are reading from the `pkl` file, then you need to describe what that data look like, so we can determine how (if possible) to store it in CSV format.

Comment: sorry for my question is. I have replaced the data pickle into data from CSV, when I run it no problem, but when running the next script, I get the problem. the problem in train_set, valid_set, test_set = numpy.load(f). For preliminary data using a different pickle with CSV, in my data CSV is data vector, whereas in pickle use matrix data.